# How do I path my Home page in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs

How do I Path my home page It is not displaying in the website

I have tired this

```
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/home" element ={ <Home/>} />
    
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which Router are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.